# Column does not exist error when using Having clause

Tags: sql

I'm following along the steps in this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/window-functions-for-analytics-in-sql-f4dac0906a55) and am having trouble with the following query:

```
SELECT Quantity, COUNT(*) AS Quantity_Counts
FROM sqlbank3
WHERE UnitPrice >= 5
GROUP BY Quantity
HAVING Quantity_Counts < 450
ORDER BY Quantity_Counts DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

ERROR:  column "quantity_counts" does not exist

LINE 5: HAVING Quantity_Counts < 450

I put everything in lower case to see if that did anything but to no avail. I have created Quantity as an integer. The query runs when I remove the HAVING clause so it's certainly finding the `Quantity_Counts` column, just not with the HAVING clause.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using a column alias in the HAVING clause is not allowed in standard SQL. But some DBMS permit it still. The author seems to be using one of those DBMS that make the exception. `LIMIT` is not standard either, by the way. In standard SQL you'd use `FETCH FIRST | NEXT n ROWS ONLY | WITH TIES` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause is supposed to be evaluated before the `SELECT` clause. You cannot use the alias defined in `SELECT` in `HAVING` for that reason.

You must use

```
HAVING COUNT(*) < 450
```

instead.

(Some DBMS allow it to use alias names in the `HAVING`clause, though.)